# Loading DropDownList dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to add a dropdown and a textbox dynamically. No errors except that I don't see the dropdown (there's no problem with the textbox).

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox TB = new TextBox();
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(TB);
            TB.ID = "TB1";
            TB.Visible = false;

            DropDownList DDL = new DropDownList();
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(DDL);
            DDL.ID = "DDL1";
            DDL.Items.Add("test", "New York");
            DDL.Visible = false;

            if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "TB")
            {
                TB.Visible = true;
            }
            else if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "DDL")
            {
                DDL.Visible = true;
            }
        }
```

I tried to add controls in Page_OnInit event, but both textbox and dropdownlist weren't displayed.

Comment: Have you check if your code is entering the if when required?

Comment: What is the value of `DropDownList1.SelectedValue`?

Comment: Another hint: if (DropDownList1. ***Selected*** Value == ...

Comment: DropDownList1.SelectedValue depends on what I select in another dropdownlist - sometimes TB, sometimes DDL (i'm sure)

Comment: If the value of DropDownList1 is being changed after page load this will not make the new DDL visible, this will only occur at page load.  How are you setting the selected value of DropDownList1 on load?